# how to remove reenable error in paypal section in magento

Tags: magento, paypal

i am tired to remove error . I got error like this 
The following error(s) occured:
  PayPal Express Checkout is not enabled.
Please re-enable the previously enabled payment solutions

Answer (score 0):

You should disable all others Paypal Payment Methods, ex: Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout), then it will no longer show this error message and you just need to re-enable again.

Good luck